# Проблема с округлением чисел

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, математика

Всем привет. Делаю алгоритм биржи, который определяет нужную сумму и коэффициент 2 игрока исходя из суммы и коэффициента 1 игрока. Алгоритм есть и на JS и на PHP.

```
var mt = {
    //Определяет коэф. 2 игрока
    findOtherRatio: function(ratioOtherPlayer){
        return ratioOtherPlayer / (ratioOtherPlayer - 1)
    },
    //Определяет прибыль 1 игрока - что также является нужной, стартовой суммой 2 игрока
    findProfit: function(start, ratio){
        return  start * ratio - start;
    },
    //Сумма вывода игрока
    findOutcome: function(start, ratio){
        return  start * ratio;
    }
};
```

Все считает практически верно. Но проблема в том, что во многих случаях цифры выглядят тысячными, миллионными... И как только я хочу придать презентабельный вид цифрам, а именно - максимум 2 цифры после запятой, то цифры перестают быть равными(вывод 1 игрока != выводу 2 игрока).

Например: представим, что 1 игрок поставил 736 руб на 1.55

```
 var cof2Player = mt.findOtherRatio(1.55).toFixed(2)
 var money2Player = mt.findProfit(736,1.55).toFixed(2)
 mt.findOutcome(money2Player, cof2Player).toFixed(2) // 1141.54
 mt.findOutcome(736, 1.55).toFixed(2) // 1140.80
```

Можно ли это как-то обойти? Как это решают различные биржи? Ведь они не показывают игрокам коэффициенты "3.8571428571428563".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что будет если использовать [math.js](http://mathjs.org/):

```
var mt = {
    //Определяет коэф. 2 игрока
    findOtherRatio: function(ratioOtherPlayer){
        return ratioOtherPlayer.div(ratioOtherPlayer.sub(1));
    },
    //Определяет прибыль 1 игрока - что также является нужной, стартовой суммой 2 игрока
    findProfit: function(start, ratio){
        return start.mul(ratio).sub(start);
    },
    //Сумма вывода игрока
    findOutcome: function(start, ratio){
        return start.mul(ratio);
    }
};

var N = math.fraction;

var cof2Player = mt.findOtherRatio(N('1.55'));
var money2Player = mt.findProfit(N('736'), N('1.55'));

var t1 = mt.findOutcome(money2Player, cof2Player); // 1140.8
var t2 = mt.findOutcome(N('736'), N('1.55')); // 1140.8
```

Для вывода можно использовать `format`:

```
math.format(2.3, {notation: 'fixed', precision: 2});  // returns '2.30'
```

Comment: верно. Без tofixed() получается. 
у 1 игрока  вывод - 1140.8
у 2 игрока вывод - 1140.7999999999997
А с toFixed() вообще не верный. Но мне надо удобно предоставлять и хранить данные в БД,  в формате 2 чисел после точки. Но так не сходится равенство.

Comment: У вас погрешность где-то накапливается. Точные вычисления спешат на помощь: http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/fractions.html. Или же используйте сравнение по модулю: `Если abs(x-y) < 1e-5, то x == y.`

Comment: Спасибо. Мне еще важнее эту логику провернуть на сервере с помощью php.

Comment: @Vadim, а как же `nodejs`?

Comment: да вот как-то так) Печально, что математику и английский в школе не учил(

Comment: начал уже на php писать.

Comment: Кстати у вас t1 и t2 содержат объект Fraction {s: 1, n: 5704, d: 5}

Comment: @Vadim, s - sign (знак), n - numerator (числитель), d - denominator (знаменатель).

Comment: я заметил, что в php в функции findOutcome() больше 2 знаков после запятой не получается, в отличие от JS

Comment: Я с php не знаком. Не могу помочь.